# Inheriting a class based upon users input

Tags: python

I have a web-app and initially I used `feedparser` to pull data from my blog. Now I thought to use `Google API` for extending various other features.

As I didn't want to break my old code and want to add the new API as an additional add-on type thing, I thought to setup a structure very similar to `BeautifulSoup` where it provides a choice to select an `HTML/ XML` parser depending upon the situation

```
BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser") 
BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
# They still support the same methods mentioned in the documentation.
```

This is what I did:

```
from apis import api1, api2
from dev_user import my_api_choice
select = { "api1" : api1, "api2": api2 }

obj = pservice (select["my_api_choice"] )
obj.method1() 
# invokes method1 of the inherited class.
```

`pservice` is very close to wrap-up class. I initially thought to write it because I could have a chance to use Google API in it.

I even made sure that api2 (which provides Google API functionality) provides same kind of methods as that of api1 (even their method names are same).

*So, is this a good way to do it? or else, how can I possibly do it in the other way..*

Comment: "Example 7. Metaclass configuration at runtime" on page 2 of the article [A Primer on Python Metaclass Programming](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html) shows doing this with metaclasses.

Comment: If I understand this problem correctly - basically you're just following the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Specifically adapting multiple versions of your API into one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create an `abstract class` `API` with some `abstract` method like `fetch` or `pull` and `inherit` it and build concrete implementations under classes like `API1` / `API2` / etc...

For example implementation of `fetch` function for Google API would be done for `HTML` and same way `fetch` function for `feedparser` would be implemented using `XML`...

Now based on your requirement or current configuration or whatever input; make a decision which `API` you want to use and create `dynamic instance` for the same, now as method names would be same in all classes you just need to fire appropriate `function` for that `instance` and you're done.

Further more, afterwards you can introduce `API3` and update your configuration - to use API3 class instance as another `content` provider.

Comment: This seems to be nice but can you tell me how to "inherit" a particular API dynamically.. on code. I used a dict to do that. But is there any other way or.. its just fine to use it

Comment: Thats interesting and it would probably be the solution to my issue.. However, does `BeautifulSoup` use delegation to provide various parsers ???

Comment: May be, I'm not aware of how beautifulsoup is developped.